# HERE Incident API Status Options

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I am using the HERE Incident API, but am battling to find what status results can be returned. I have been through all the online documentation and don't seem to find the various results that can be returned for TRAFFICITEMSTATUSSHORTDESC. I see ACTIVE in the results, but that is the only one I have ever seen. Please can someone advise.

Comment: Please share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/resource-parameters-incidents.html

*The accepted status values include: active, inactive, deleted, and expired.*